# Spring Integration DSL History issue

Tags: java, java-8, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-ftp

I have to setup the flows dynamically.

Example:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FTPFlow {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext integrationFlowContext;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void setup(){


        integrationFlowContext.registration(flow()).register();

    }
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {

        DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPort(252);
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setUsername("user");
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPassword("password");
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(defaultFtpSessionFactory).preserveTimestamp(true)
                        .localDirectory(new File("D:/tools/input"))
                        .regexFilter("yo.txt")
                        .remoteDirectory("/testing")
                        .deleteRemoteFiles(true),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .transform((GenericTransformer<File, File>) file -> {

                    log.info("Dummy transformer. ");
                    return file;
                })
                .handle(o -> {

                    log.info("history {}", o.getHeaders());
                })
                .get();
    }
}
```

The springboot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMessageHistory
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The headers don't contain the history but if I don't use the IntegrationContext and use the `@Bean` directly on the method flow then I can see the history.

Do I have to enable the history when using `IntegrationFlowContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I actually found out myself. Just adding answer for other people**

When you are using `IntegrationFlowContext`  you have to provide the `"id"` otherwise the history is not reserved.

```
 integrationFlowContext.registration(flow()).id("tesflow").register();
```

Comment: I would like to understand more your concern. Since you don't restrict Message History for some particular pattern, I don't see a difference for static flow id or generated one; the history must be generated anyway.

Comment: I have uploaded the project here https://github.com/muhdkhokhar/stackoverflow

Comment: If you run the springboot application you'll see there is no history in the headers

Comment: You'll require some FTP server for this though

Comment: OK. I'll play with that a bit later. I believe it can be much simple and without any external service requirements. Just plain Inbound Channel Adapter registered at runtime!

Comment: Well, you are right: this is an expected behavior. See Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history-config - `Now every named component (component that has an 'id' defined) is tracked.`. So, this is really important to give a reasonable `id` for components to be tracked by Message History. Essentially this is the point of Message History: to track those components you want and by default they are all but only with an `id`.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan I do find the documents can be confusing. I also struggle alot becuase lot of documents are based on XML and I use DSL but so far with your and Gary help I have maanaged to completed one part of big project. I am introducing Spring INTEGRATION DSL in my team :)

Comment: Please, don't hesitate to raise GH issues if you think that something could be improved. Also contribution is always welcome! Even if that is about some simple some to add or docs typo or as you mentioned confusion mitigation.

Comment: Forgot to mention: this is an answer to the question, so, don't forget to accept it yourself! :smile: